# Is there a way to determine how much power/energy it takes to run my R-code?

Tags: r, performance, processing-efficiency, energy, consumption

I'm interested to know if there is an r package (or any other sort of approach) that helps determine how much power my r-code is using.

What sort of factors would this depend on? Run time of my code, efficiency of my code, etc.?

Many thanks for any help!

Best,

Sebastian

Comment: It would also depend on your hardware and even the room temperature ... I don't think you will get a useful estimate without actually measuring power consumption (with an electricity meter) and using that for benchmarks.

Comment: Thanks, Roland. Alternatively, are there models to (roughly) estimate energy consumption of training ML models? This would achieve a similar purpose for me.